# UVM- One config file vs a variety of config files(config file per test)

Tags: configuration, uvm

I have varaibles in the sequence and in the transaction that I want to change each test.

What is the best option? To have config file to each test, or to have one config file and set the val of the varaibles in the test file (uvm_test)?

Comment: I think it's always best to have one config file and allow each test to change the variables as they run. Think about a game ... there's one options file for all game modes.

Answer (score 1):

Screw the config files, use SV +plus arguments.  UVM comes with uvm_cmdline_processor helps you parse +plus arguments in the testbench.

The benefit of using +plus argument is you don't have to recompile and re-elaborate the testbench if you want to try out some new config values.  Just re-run the sim with different input arguments.